# How to find the first index from the linked list, where the certain value is found using recursion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, linked-list

I have a basic singly linked list and I try to find the first index from the linked list, where the certain value is found using recursion. I have initialized the linked list in this way:

```
class Linkedlist:

    def __init__(self, value, tail):
        self.value = value
        self.tail = tail
```

After this there are other methods that work fine, but the problem is how I can return the first index in the linked list, where the value x is found? I have tried the next one, but it only works for the first index (0).

```
   def index(self, x):

        index = 0
        if x == self.value:
            return 0
        else:
            return Linkedlist.index(self.tail, index+1)
```

I think the problem is that the index stays always zero. How I can work around this?

Comment: What is `Cell`?

Comment: @L0KiZ please elaborate more.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It was different class from my testing. Should have been Linkedlist

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Apparently the issue was with using the extra index trying to go through the linked list, but thanks to @Heap Overflow, my issue was solved

Comment: For the record, you are better off doing it with a loop than recursive since python has a max recursion depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for passing an index. If the value is right here, return 0. Otherwise get the index in the tail and add 1.

```
def index(self, x):
    if x == self.value:
        return 0
    return self.tail.index(x) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`index()` needs to take the value you're looking for (`x`) and also the current index which is initially 0.

Assumptions I'm making:

- `value` is the head of the linked list.
- `tail` is a linked list.
- If there is no next term, `tail` is None.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value, tail):
        self.value = value
        self.tail = tail

    def index(self, x, i=0):
        if self.value == x:
             return i
        if self.tail is None:
             raise IndexError
        return self.tail.index(x, i+1)
```